# Publicizing S[O/F/U] API wrappers?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, api

Under the assumption that an API is forthcoming (there certainly have [been alot of questions about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api)) what's the proper way to "announce" a wrapper library for it?

I [threw one together](http://code.google.com/p/stackexchange-api/)* (prompted by [Maxim Z.'s then incomplete one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31200/net-library-for-stack-overflow-api)) based on what little of an "api" already exists, went through packaging it up, and then came to the realization that there isn't really an established etiquette for such things.

Last time I wrote an [SO tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891158/how-do-you-place-stackoverflow-flair-on-facebook-closed) it was permissible to post a Q/A on SO, and then link it into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248296/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow); which has since been migrated to Meta.  So, things have obviously changed.  Rather than *just* throw up a Q/A blindly hoping that was alright, I figured it'd be best to inquire about etiquette as well.

<sub>*Yes yes, ulterior motive detected.</sub>

Comment: So cool, btw! Yes, this is an interesting issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publicize them on meta.  The community pretty aggressively migrates anything that's about SO (even if it's a programming question) to meta.

Further, anyone who wants to access the API is already aware that meta is the place to be, so the audience is already here.